# insert with select statement with SQLQuery

Tags: insert

I am working with spring 2.5 mvc and in one method in Dao I want to save records with insert statement. However, I have to use the values returning from select query as values part. I am using sql developer.

```
String SQLbsv = "INSERT INTO abc_table_name (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)"
            + " (SELECT seq_Name.NEXTVAL, h,i, j,k, l, m"

            + " from abc_table_name abc where abc.ID = :id)";

    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(SQLbsv);
    query.setInteger("id", gelen_parametre); 
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

However, it doesn't work. I can't use hql also. Is there any solution to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Wrong results?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, there is no error, but it doesn't save anything. the variable result returns 55, there are 55 records that should be saved but nothing saved.

Comment: Have you commited the transaction?

Comment: I only do this code in Dao method. Is there any code that I should add after int result = query.executeUpdate();